# How to prevent swapping on Mac osx?

Tags: privacy

I am inclined to run Tails through a virtual machine so that I could chain two VPNs. One running through the host Mac osx and one more running from inside the virtual machine that's running Tails.

However on Tails website, it says that host operating systems likely uses swapping which copies part of the RAM to the hard drive. Is there a command or program that prevents swapping on Mac osx?

Comment: Are you using VMware Player or VirtualBox ? Also, what is the space you reserved for your VM ?

Comment: The question is about swapping, not about information security. It just so happens to be about Tails, but it could have been any other OS. Voting to move to SuperUser.

Comment: it's virtual box and I reserved 4gbs for it but since I am a new user what's SuperUser?

Comment: @ChristianCollier: StackExchange is actually composed of a network of different Q&A each one dedicated to a specific topic. It happens that some questions are a bit cross-topics, so it's up to the community to try to help you to determine where you could get the most pertinent information. Here is about IT Security, [su] is about end-user computing, personally however I would tend to think that [unix.se] would most closely match your question. As a side note, you can [see the full listing of other sites here](https://stackexchange.com/sites), it is not limited to IT.

Comment: As stated in my previous comment, this question seems specific to the Unix part of OS-X and would therefore be more suited on [unix.se].

Comment: That's new to me. Can I ask how it's related to Linux beside tails being Linux since I want to prevent swapping on Mac OS X?

Comment: @ChristianCollier You could try on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), the Apple stack exchange, but since OS X is based on BSD (a flavour of Unix) and swapping is a very low-level operating system question, you're more likely to get a good answer from the unix community.

Comment: Thank you I am not as proficient as you in operating systems. Will go to Linux and ask.